# Entity Framework 5: RelationShips and Attached/Detached objects

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm a bit confused how to work properly with many-to-many relationships in locally created objects.
I've prepared a small example to demonstrate the issue.

There are two tables and one mapping table:
[image: Database structure]

And data in tables:

[image: db data]

Entity Framework has created two tables and many-to-many relation:

[image: EF]

Now run the application and load single student (with ID=1 and his classrooms).
If student was loaded from the database then everything is fine and EF gets 2 classrooms:

[image]

But in case user was created locally (with the same Id but changed Name) and attached to the EF then classrooms are not loaded (`studentLocal` variable).

The same situation if I try to load student from EF - it gets the local user (`student` variable has `Name="xx"`) and no classrooms:

[image]

On the view user can change classrooms for student as well as change student properties so I need to update Student table and merge StudentClassroom table.

1. What is the best way to deal in this case? I don't want to load each
   postback student entity again and again.
2. Is there a way to load
       Classrooms for locally created Student which exist in the database?
3. How to merge StudentClassroom records? I know only one - load
   existed records and new one and merge then either deleting all of
   them and recreating from the new list either manually determining
   which records should be deleted/updated/created. Is there a better
   approach?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that EF is not creating the right tables for your model. It should be creating 3 classes not 2.  Probably the reason it isn't is that you don't have the relations set up properly in the database. If you are using SQL Server try using the diagram feature to check your relationships and Primary Keys are correctly set up before you set up the model.

Comment: Hi Kirsten! The first screenshot was created from the SSMS diagram. As I understand EF creates only association if no other columns exist in a table but two FK only...